# vbScript to execute all files in a dir

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I'm trying to write a vbScript that will execute all files in a given directory (will be mostly batch files).

I've tried to modify a script that deletes all files but I'm not able to get it to work.

Here is what I have:

```
Option Explicit 
'=========================================================================== 
'  Scheduled Task - Visual Basic ActiveX Script 
'=========================================================================== 

Call ExecuteDirectory("c:\users\public\documents\schedule\daily") 


Function ExecuteDirectory(strPath2Folder) 
    Dim fso, f, fc, f1, strFiles, intFiles
    Dim WshShell

    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    strFiles = "" 

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    If (fso.FolderExists(strPath2Folder)) Then 
        Set f = fso.GetFolder(strPath2Folder) 
        Set fc = f.Files 

        '-- Execute each file in Folder 
        For Each f1 in fc 
            strFiles = strFiles & f1.Name & vbCrLf 
            msgbox strPath2Folder & "\" & strFiles

            WshShell.Run Chr(34) & strFiles & Chr(34), 1, true
        Next 

        Set f1 = Nothing 
        Set fc = Nothing 
        Set f = Nothing 


    End If 
    Set fso = Nothing 
End Function
```

The msgbox line displays the full path and file name that I want to execute, but the run line generates file not found error.

Comment: Im assuming it works for the first file then fails for all files after the first one. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

The variable `strFiles` continually builds up a list of files with line breaks in between.  For example, if your folder contains the files "test1.bat" and "test2.bat", you will end up with this:

**Iteration 1**:
strFiles =

```
test1.bat
```

**Iteration 1**:
strFiles =

```
test1.bat
test2.bat
```

I don't think this is what you want to do.  If you want to just run each script in order, you should just pass the single script name.

Try changing the inner loop to this:

```
    For Each f1 in fc  
        Dim fileToRun
        fileToRun = strPath2Folder & "\" & f1.Name
        WshShell.Run Chr(34) & fileToRun & Chr(34), 1, true 
    Next
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a very sloppy approach.  If you are needing to execute an entire directory of batch files at one time, then you are not using them correctly.  You should only need one batch file or one script an any time.  I would begin looking at your whole system for a better approach to whatever it is that you are trying to accomplish.